# How to find out the reason of the slow loading of the web page?

Tags: entity-framework, web, performance

The homepage i guess is alright. Each time it take around 1s to load. ( i am using YSlow plugin)
http://pocomaru.cloudapp.net/

However if I go to a specify category, for example:
http://pocomaru.cloudapp.net/category/45/iphone-4-4s-cases
It still takes 1.7-2s to load.

I am expecting a very fast load that is at most 1s. The page only contains one major sql call:
get products belong to a category, and there is only 18 products in that category.

I am aware of normal technology for increasing the page loading time like lazy load pictures etc. but my problem here is that the initial page load takes too long.

I am not sure what is the reason. the database is sql azure web version. Can any one shed some light on it? I am using .net EF.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

I think this page can give you some insights as to what are the reasons and what you can do to make it better:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a serverside issue.

I'd get hold of a profiler (some versions of Visual Studio have this [built in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)) and firstly run it on your development machine - that's the quickest way of understanding the performance characteristics of your app. Usually, going through this process will show a number of opportunities to improve application performance.

If your app runs beautifully on your development machine, but is slow on Azure, you have to dig into the infrastructure issues. Start by [collecting performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411542.aspx) - that usually shows up what's going on (indexes that are missing on production are a classic).

Answer (score 1):

How big is the table and do you have indexes on the fields you are using to filter?  It looks like when the page is completely cold (nobody visited in a while) it can take as long as 20 seconds: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120726_5R_108A/

New Relic has a deal with Azure where you can get their "standard" product for free - http://newrelic.com/azure.  That should be able to tell you where the time is going pretty quickly.

Comment: I agree with pmeenan. I also ran a webpagetest, and there seems to be even more 404 errors now http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120726_20_13F8/ . Neville K and refhat also gave good advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few front-end performance improvements you can make but ultimately if you want to have a sub 1s load time you need to sort out the back-end.

The gap between the request and response for the HTML is about 1.5s so you need to analyse what's happening on the server.